# Oracle pivot function with two columns

Tags: sql, oracle

How to display the number of employees in each department with each salary in oracle

something like this

```
department_id salar_equal_1000  salar_equal_20000 city_boston city_detroit city_none
10            2                 3                 2           1            2
20            1                 2                 1           2            0
```

table contains data like this

```
department_id   salary city
10              1000   boston
10              1000   boston
10              2000   detroit
10              2000   
10              2000   
20              1000   boston
20              2000   detroit
20              2000   detroit
```

I guess i have to use the pivot statement but i am not sure need some help on this

Comment: Great.  What's your question?  What data are you using?

Comment: I updated the question with the input data

Comment: Perhaps, "pivot" and/or "dynamic pivot" are the terms you want to search for.

Comment: @jbaliuka the link you posted talks about when there is only one column in the pivot function..now here i have two columns

Comment: @AndriyM I am searching for pivot function with two columns..thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select
    department_id, 
    sum(case when salary = 1000 then 1 else 0 end) as salar_equal_1000,
    sum(case when salary = 2000 then 1 else 0 end) as salar_equal_2000,
    sum(case when city   = 'boston' then 1 else 0 end) as city_boston,
    sum(case when city   = 'detroit' then 1 else 0 end) as city_detroit,
    sum(case when city   is null then 1 else 0 end) as city_none
from
    employees
group by department_id
order by department_id
```

Edited again:

See it here on fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3564c/6

Comment: @javanoob this solve your question?

Comment: hi, this is useful but can you please let me know if there is one more column for example city and we need the number of employees in each city..Thanks so much for your answer

Comment: where the cities enter in your problem? You have to have any link or data for the cities on your table in order to solve what you need. With just department_id and salary it is impossible.

Comment: I was going to modify the source data..did you downvote this question :)

Comment: I was looking at the pivot function in oracle 11g but i am confused as how to enter two columns in that..with just salary column i was able to do..but how do i enter city column..??

Comment: Just as the same way! I've edited the answer to give you your result plus the sqlfiddle, so you can see it.

Comment: How about the city_none column in the output? once again Thank you so much for your time and answer

Comment: it was syntax error.now it is working fine..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47104/discussion-between-javanoob-and-jorge-campos)

Answer (score 1):

```
Hi please go through the following example, Might be it will help you.
```

If you are working with oracle10g this is the format,
 if 11g pivot function is there

```
WITH cte(dept_id,salary) AS (SELECT 10,1000 FROM dual
                                      UNION ALL
SELECT 10,1000 FROM dual
UNION ALL
                             SELECT 10,1000 FROM dual
                             UNION ALL
                             SELECT 20,1000 FROM dual
                             UNION ALL
                             SELECT 10,2000 FROM dual
                             UNION ALL
                             SELECT 10,2000 FROM dual
                             UNION ALL
                             SELECT 20,1000 FROM dual
                             UNION ALL
                             SELECT 20,2000 FROM dual
                             UNION ALL
                             SELECT 20,2000 FROM dual
                            ),


TEMP as(SELECT
    dept_id,
     count(salary) cnt,salary
FROM
    cte
GROUP BY salary, dept_id)

SELECT dept_id,sum(CASE WHEN salary=1000 THEN cnt ELSE 0 END)salary_1000,
sum(CASE WHEN salary=2000 THEN cnt ELSE 0 END) salary_2000 FROM TEMP
GROUP BY dept_id
```

Comment: Can you tell me how do i add city also to the query, i modified my question